# How to make one plot's fill color match another plots line color in GGplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset where I'm trying to make 3 graphs for the same variable (Den Volume) grouped by Species Group.  I factorize the Species Group Column to control the order of the display, but the color order is not preserved between line and fill.

Here's the code snippet:

```
ggthemr("flat")

cts_table_Complete$SppGroups <- 
  factor(cts_table_Complete$SppGroups, 
         levels = c("None", 
                    "Arachnids",
                    "Herptiles (excl. CTS)", 
                    "Kangaroo Rat", 
                    "Rodents")
         ) #reorder so "None" is first    

vol_gg_bar <- ggplot(cts_table_Complete, aes(x = Den.Volume.in3, 
                                             fill = SppGroups)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,200)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'bin', alpha = 0.8) +
  theme(legend.position = "left") +
  labs(fill = "Species Group", 
       x = "Den Volume (Cubic Inches)",
       y = "Number of Observations")


vol_gg_dense <- ggplot(cts_table_Complete, aes(x = Den.Volume.in3, 
                                               color = SppGroups)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 200)) +
  theme(legend.position = "left") +
  labs(fill = "Species Group", 
       x = "Den Volume (Cubic Inches)",
       y = "Porportion of Observations") +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.6, size = 2) +
  scale_color_discrete(aesthetics = c("colour"))
  

grid.arrange(vol_gg_bar, vol_gg_dense, ncol=2)
```

Unfortunately the bar chart's fill comes out like this:

[image: bar chart fill]

and the lines on the density chart come out like this:

[image]

I'd like to change the lines to match the fill, so because I also have  a box plot using fill colors and I'd like all 3 to match.

Comment: Hi @Sam Ericksen, could you please provided us some data using `dput()`?

Comment: You can use the `scale_fill_*()` and `scale_color_*()` functions in order to match between these plots.  We don't see your data, so it's not clear how your column that you are using for the aesthetics is setup - the detailed answer for your case may depend on this.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!
Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to directly share the data right now.  I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the scale_color_*() commands though.  In both plots, the legend is referring to the same column, a column of 5 different factors, ordered by level as indicated in the second line of code if that helps at all.

Comment: Looks like `ggthemr("flat")` overrides the default ggplot2 color palettes. However, I guess that adding `scale_color_discrete` switches back to the ggplot2 defaults. Hence I would try with removing the `scale_color_discrete` (which IMHO is not needed) or if that will not fix your issue try with `scale_colour_ggthemr_d()`.

Comment: Amazing, thanks @stefan, scale_colour_ggthemr_d() fixed it. I'm new to the site, is there some way I can mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: Great. I just prepared a simple reprex of your issue and added it as an answer. This way you could mark my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `ggthemr("flat")` overrides the default ggplot2 color palettes. However, looks like that does not work in all instances.

But according to the docs

> To avoid this and keep using ggthemr colours in these instances, please add a scale_colour_ggthemr_d() layer to your ggplot call.

Hence, adding `scale_colour_ggthemr_d()` instead of `scale_color_discrete` fixes your issue:

Using `mtcars` as example data:

```r
library(ggthemr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

ggthemr("flat")

vol_gg_bar <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, fill = factor(am))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,200)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'bin', alpha = 0.8) +
  theme(legend.position = "left") +
  labs(fill = "Species Group", 
       x = "Den Volume (Cubic Inches)",
       y = "Number of Observations")


vol_gg_dense <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, colour = factor(am))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 200)) +
  theme(legend.position = "left") +
  labs(fill = "Species Group", 
       x = "Den Volume (Cubic Inches)",
       y = "Porportion of Observations") +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.6, size = 2) +
  scale_colour_ggthemr_d()

grid.arrange(vol_gg_bar, vol_gg_dense, ncol=2)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Warning: Removed 4 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

[image]